# Kotlin create new object from others two based on id

Tags: kotlin

What's the current best kotlin idiomatic way of merging two data classes into another one:

```
Data class A:
id: Int,
name: String

Data class B:
id: Int,
note: String

Data class C:
data1: A,
data2: B

val result = MutableLiveData<List<C>>()
val array1:List<A> = getA()
val array2:List<B> = getB()
```

array1 and array2 have Ids, I need a new list with objects of type C based on array1 with the extra data I find based on the Id in array2. On Java I would iterate over array1, search the id in array2 and construct a new object in each iteration adding it to "result", how can you achieve this with Kotlin?

What I tried so far and it seems to work but it's not kotlin-style:

```
            val array1 = getA()
            val array2 = getB()
            val resultTemp: ArrayList<C> = arrayListOf()
            for (obj in array1 ) {
                var noteString = ""
                for (obj2 in array2) {
                    if (obj2.id == obj1.id) {
                        noteString = obj2.note
                    }
                }
                val objC = C(obj.id, obj, noteString)
                resultTemp.add(objC)
            }
            result.value = resultTemp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear from you question whether instance of `B` can be null in `C`. If true then simply

```
val result = arrayA.map { a -> C(a, arrayB.find { a.id == it.id }) }
```

else

```
val result = arrayA.mapNotNull { a -> arrayB.find { a.id == it.id }?.let { C(a, it) } }
```

Comment: *yes, not always is data in B present for each ID in A

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work completely, if A has 5 items and B 2 items the resulting list has only 2 items. What I would expect are the 5 items from A where 2 of them now have the data from B added.

Comment: Wow, yes, the first one worked, I needed to change it to val result = arrayA.map { a -> C(a, arrayB.find { a.id == it.id }?.note) } I had the option to use ?, !!!, or "let", but with "let" the resulting code wouldn't compile. Thank you very much! I must study this intensively.